# $(document).ready or $(function(){}): Which way is the correct one?

Tags: jquery

I'm using **jQuery** to run my code after the DOM is ready and I've been using the following idiom

```
jQuery(function(){
    //my code
});
```

but in many places I've seen people doing

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     //my code
});
```

What's the difference between the two? If nothing, then why do most people use the second way?